# String manipulation of HTML with String.Replace, replace relative paths

Tags: c#, string

i need to change links to images in a html file and i encounterd a problem.
i want to use `String.Replace` to change the url but some urls have their url shortend with `../` instead of a folder name.

Now i have the following string:

```
string temp = "/english/img/logo_btn.gif";
```

I want this string to look like this:

```
../../../logo_btn.gif
```

so i can find and replace it in the html.

The problem i keep having is that i can't get rid of the text between the `/`.
I would like to avoid regular expresions if possible but if there is no other way, so be it.

Does anyone know of a way to acomplish this?

Comment: It's better to provide your actual code and specify what's wrong with it. There are no mind-readers here.

Comment: Check out this website: http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace

Comment: Note that i've edited my answer in the moment that you've accepted it. `Enumerable.Count` is better than `String.Split` since it doesn't need to create redundant strings and also calculates the correct number in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `temp.Count(c => c == '/')` to get the number of `/`, use the `Path`-class to build it:

```
string temp = "/english/img/logo_btn.gif"; 
string folders = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("../", temp.Count(c => c == '/')));
string result = Path.Combine(folders, Path.GetFileName(temp));
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to use this regex pattern:

`(.*?\/)`

and replace it with `../`

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/2yppetYqGf)

Comment: not exactly what im looking for but it did give me na idea. so thanks